# Geoserver installed but some components not working

Tags: geoserver

I have installed Geoserver 2.6 on windows 7 32 bit os. Java version is 7.

- First: installed with installer.exe
- Second: installed tomcat8 and web archive

I installed two way. But some components are not working on admin panel. **Layer Preview, Stores, Styles, Layers, Layer Groups** menus are not working. All menu items are giving this error.

I installed 3 different mechines, but  not working.

Error reposrt is like this:

```
ERROR [wicket.RequestCycle] - Exception in rendering component: [Component id = filterMatch]
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Exception in rendering component: [Component id = filterMatch]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.renderComponent(Component.java:2725)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebComponent.onRender(WebComponent.java:62)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2517)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1440)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1603)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAssociatedMarkup(MarkupContainer.java:696)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.Panel.onComponentTagBody(Panel.java:114)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.renderComponent(Component.java:2686)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1538)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2517)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1440)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1603)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1527)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onComponentTagBody(Form.java:1995)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.renderComponent(Component.java:2686)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1538)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2517)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1440)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1603)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAssociatedMarkup(MarkupContainer.java:696)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.Panel.onComponentTagBody(Panel.java:114)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.renderComponent(Component.java:2686)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1538)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2517)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1440)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1603)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1527)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.renderComponent(Component.java:2686)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1538)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2517)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.autoAdd(MarkupContainer.java:229)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.resolver.MarkupInheritanceResolver.resolve(MarkupInheritanceResolver.java:66)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.resolver.ComponentResolvers.resolve(ComponentResolvers.java:81)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1444)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1603)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1527)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.renderComponent(Component.java:2686)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1538)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2517)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.autoAdd(MarkupContainer.java:229)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.resolver.MarkupInheritanceResolver.resolve(MarkupInheritanceResolver.java:73)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.resolver.ComponentResolvers.resolve(ComponentResolvers.java:81)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1444)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1554)
    at org.apache.wicket.Page.onRender(Page.java:1575)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2517)
    at org.apache.wicket.Page.renderPage(Page.java:913)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.respond(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.respond(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:105)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1258)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1329)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1436)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:484)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doGet(WicketServlet.java:138)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:159)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:135)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.vfny.geoserver.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unmatched braces in the pattern.
    at java.text.MessageFormat.applyPattern(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.wicket.model.StringResourceModel.getString(StringResourceModel.java:546)
    at org.apache.wicket.model.StringResourceModel.load(StringResourceModel.java:647)
    at org.apache.wicket.model.StringResourceModel.load(StringResourceModel.java:181)
    at org.apache.wicket.model.LoadableDetachableModel.getObject(LoadableDetachableModel.java:120)
    at org.apache.wicket.model.StringResourceModel$AssignmentWrapper.getObject(StringResourceModel.java:241)
    at org.apache.wicket.model.StringResourceModel$AssignmentWrapper.getObject(StringResourceModel.java:216)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.getDefaultModelObject(Component.java:1720)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.getDefaultModelObjectAsString(Component.java:1739)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label.onComponentTagBody(Label.java:114)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.renderComponent(Component.java:2686)
    ... 151 more
```

Comment: Version 2.6 has been very reliable to install for me. Which browser you are using?

Comment: using chrome and internet explorer

Comment: Make one more trial, it is quick: Use the binary (zip) package, unzip it into c:\geoserver_test and run the "startup.bat" in the \bin folder. Stop other services running in port 8080 first.

Comment: Someone suggested to change regional settings on client machine in [this link](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Geoserver-2-6-2-installed-but-menu-items-Component-id-filterMatch-error-tp5187161p5187945.html) But It shouldn't be a solution.

Comment: it could be a corrupt download, but most likely issue is some other program is getting in the way

Comment: I have sama problem. Layer Preview, Stores, Styles, Layers, Layer Groups menus are not working. Can anyone solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the language setting for the browser.
I had the same problem.
When I changed it to English instead of Turkish and restarted the browser, the problem was solved.

[image]

[image]